# Issue With Checking If Number Contained in Index Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

So I have a dataframe, lets call it df1, that looks like the following.

```
    Index   ID
    1       90
    2       508
    3       692
    4       944
    5       1172
    6       1998
    7       2022
```

Now if I call (508 == df['ID']).any() it returns true as it should. But if I have another dataframe, df2, that looks like the following:

```
    Index  Num
    1      83
    2      508
    3      912
```

and I want to check if the Nums are contained in the IDs from df1 using iloc returns an error of len() of unsized object. This is the exact code I've used:

```
   (df2.iloc[1][0] == df2['ID']).any()
```

which returns the error mentioned above. I've also tried setting a variable to df1.iloc[1][0], didn't work, and calling int() on that variable, also didn't work. Can anyone provide some insight on this?

Comment: What output do you want it to be? `True` here?

Comment: `np.int64(3) == df['ID']` also returns the same error. Although you said converting to int didn't work; it should. Changing the order should also work. (`(df['ID'] == df2.iloc[1][0]).any()`

Comment: What is the desired output?

Comment: Also note the typo: `(df2.iloc[1][0] == df2['ID']).any()` should be `(df2.iloc[1][0] == df1['ID']).any()`

Comment: Yes the output should be true. And yea I mistyped that, should be df1['ID']

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try turning it around.

```
(df1['ID'] == df2.iloc[1][0]).any()

True
```

This is happening as a result of how the `==` is being handled for the objects being passed to it.

In this case you have the first object of type

```
type(df2.iloc[1][0])

numpy.int64
```

And the second of type

```
pandas.core.series.Series
```

`==` or `__eq__` doesn't handle that combination well.

However, this works too:

```
(int(df2.iloc[1][0]) == df1['ID']).any()
```

Or:

```
(int(df2.iloc[1, 0]) == df1['ID']).any()
```

Comment: Huh that's really interesting that flipping it would work. Really didn't think something that simple would fix it but thanks! And good explanation too

Comment: As a followup, say I want to append the Nums that aren

Comment: As a followup, say I want to append the Nums not in df1 to the end of ID. I have the if statement, but when I go to append, I get "cannot concatenate a non-NDFrame object". This was using df1.append(df2.iloc[0][0]) and df1.append(int(df2.iloc[0][0]))

Answer (score 1):

This works

```
 (df['ID']==df2.iloc[1][0]).any()
```

Comment: @Alexander it was a typo meant df

Comment: Great, that's really interesting how the == works and that flipping the order solves it. As a followup, say I want to append the Nums not in df1 to the end of ID. I have the if statement, but when I go to append, I get "cannot concatenate a non-NDFrame object". This was using df1.append(df2.iloc[0][0]) and df1.append(int(df2.iloc[0][0]))

Comment: @JSolomonCulp you can't add a single value to a dataframe like that, you need to add the whole Series. df1.append(df2.loc[0]) will work

Comment: Alright I was afraid of that. With what I'm actually working on, the dataframes are different sizes, so df2 has Num but then a bunch of other data in it. Ideally, I want to just add the value of Num to the df1 which only has one column. I guess I could just expand df1 to be filled with a bunch of NaN?

Comment: Try putting the value df2.iloc[0][0] into a series with the column name 'ID' and seeing if that works, or yeah you could expand df1 or remove columns form df2

Comment: df1.append(pd.DataFrame(data=[df2.iloc[0][0]], columns=['ID']), ignore_index=True) this works @JSolomonCulp

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Something like this to check if the `ID` column is in the `Num` column of `df2`:

```
>>> df1.ID.isin(df2.Num)
Index
1    False
2     True
3    False
4    False
5    False
6    False
7    False
Name: ID, dtype: bool
```

or:

```
>>> df2.Num.isin(df1.ID)
Index
1    False
2     True
3    False
Name: Num, dtype: bool
```

Or if you just want to see the matching numbers by index location:

```
>>> df2.where(df2.Num.isin(df1.ID) * df2.Num, np.nan)
       Num
Index     
1      NaN
2      508
3      NaN
```